# Adjoints to cofree modules tensor?

Tags: category-theory, modules, homological-algebra, tensor-products, adjoint-functors

If $M$ is a cofree $R$-module and $A,B$ are arbitrary $R$-modules then, is there a left adjoint to the functor $M\otimes_R -$,  i.e. is there an endofunctor $F$ on $_R \mathrm{Mod}$ such that $\mathrm{Hom}_R(F(A),B) \cong \mathrm{Hom}_R(A,M\otimes_R B)$?

Comment: I have found the following definition, do you use the same? $M$ is called cofree if it is a direct product of copies of $\hom_{\mathbb{Z}}(R,\mathbb{Q}/\mathbb{Z})$.

Comment: Yup, thats the one I use

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$M \otimes_R -$ is almost never continuous and therefore has no left adjoint.

Comment: Ya I though so too, since it doesn't preserve the limits of a familly of non-finitely presented and flat modules :/

Thanks again Martin :)